# Recent activity display issue - long tags

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, tags, reputation-display

When the question tags are very long, the recent activity div gets pushed down:

[image: flair pushed down]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is intentional (where else would it go?).  Tagging [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) accordingly.